# Confusion about singularity of $\sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z)=\sin z$ $(z\not=1)$. I'm confused about the data of my book which I've read. My book says that: "*$f$ has removable singularity at $z=1$*".

My question: how it is possible? I know  $\sin z$ as an entire function.

Is it nothing but a printing mistake or the book is correct? If the book is correct then how?

Comment: Perhaps all the author is suggesting is that $f(z)$ could be defined as $\sin(z)$ for $z\ne 1$ and, as yet, undefined for $z=1$.  However, we can define a function $g(z)=f(z)$ for $z\ne 1$ and $g(1)=\sin(1)$.  This produces a continuous function at $1$.

Comment: It looks like a typo . Likely meant  $ f(z)=(\sin z)/z.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(z)$ may be entire, but that does not mean the function you have been provided with is. Maybe if I write $f$ a little more clearly, your doubt will be cleared:

$f(z)=
\begin{cases}
\sin(z), & z\neq1\\[4px]
\text{undefined}, & z=1
 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that as defined, $f$ has a singularity which is the nonexistence of $f(z)$ at $z=1$.  This singularity can be removed by replacing the point removed by the statement $z\neq 1$.

I can see why it's confusing because you might think the book is saying $z\neq 1$ removes the singularity, but it's not, $z\neq 1$ is creating it and you would remove the singularity by putting $z=1$ back in.